# wifi "network DISABLED" device not ready

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, realtek-wireless

I am running ubuntu 16.04 LTS. When I first installed it Earlier this year i had network UNCLAIMED issues due to the Realtek rtl8732de drive. which i fixed using the correct answer from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966473/how-do-i-install-ndiswrapper-support-for-an-unsupported-rtl8723de-wireless-modul).

Yesterday, after updating and restarting, my wifi wasn't connecting again because of the same issue, this time i fixed it using the same method, but from [a different source](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Wireless-and-Networking/No-WIFI-presence-on-Ubuntu-16-04/td-p/6633337).

Which did fix the "network UNCLAIMED" issue only to replace it with a "network DISABLED" one. from the wifi icon on top right: enable networking and enable wifi are both ticked, but "wifi networks" is greyed out, and under it "device not ready".

result of sudo lshw -C network:

```
  *-network               
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: eno1
   version: 15
   serial: ac:e2:d3:d2:31:da
   size: 1Gbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.1.22 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
   resources: irq:16 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:a2104000-a2104fff memory:a2100000-a2103fff

  *-network DISABLED
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: wlo1
   version: 00
   serial: 40:9f:38:a9:ad:41
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8723de driverversion=4.15.0-33-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:132 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a2000000-a200ffff
```

result of rfkill list:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I tried pretty much all solutions i could find, updating/upgrading, restarting network manager services, auto-remove, etc. I also tried removing both the drivers i had installed for solving the network unclaimed issue (rm -rf and dkms remove --all), and reinstalling only the https://github.com/jeremyb31/rtl8723de.git one. But the problem persists.

result of dkms status:

```
bcmwl, 6.30.223.271+bdcom, 4.15.0-33-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8723de, 5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414: added
```

I would appreciate any help

Edits:

Kernel version:

```
4.15.03-33-generic
```

After removing the driver incompatible with newer kernels, and installing the https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git, i still have the network DISABLED error, but the dkms status changed:

```
bcmwl, 6.30.223.271+bdcom, 4.15.0-33-generic, x86_64: installed
rtlwifi-new, 0.6, 4.15.0-33-generic, x86_64: installed
```

I think the issue now is that the wifi network's driver is still set to rtl8723de, not rtlwifi, however. I can't blacklist rtl8723de from /etc/modeprobe.d/blacklist.conf, because, one of the outputs of lsmod | grep rtl8723de:

```
rtlwifi               163840  5 phydm_mod,rtl_pci,btcoexist,rtl8723_common,rtl8723de
```

the driver that i want to use includes the old driver's name, so i don't know if/how i can blacklist the old driver

Comment: @pomsky i edited the question to include kernel version

Comment: That module is not compatible with newer kernels, try the one from Larry Finger's repo.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Realtek Semiconductor RTL8723DE Device d723 issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/983251/realtek-semiconductor-rtl8723de-device-d723-issue). Please try the one from Larry Finger's repo and report back.

Comment: @pomsky, yeah i already had that link open, if it works, should i delete the question or leave it to be marked as duplicate ?

Comment: @pomsky the new driver is installed, but i'm still having the network DISABLED issue, i will edit the question to show the new dkms status output

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug with the 4.15.0-33 kernel and the rtl8723be wireless device.

See this bug report [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1788997/comments/21) or [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1788997/).

Also, no matter which driver you use, **dkms status** should show it as **installed**, not **added**.

Comment: will downgrading my kernel solve the problem ?

Comment: Using GRUB, just try booting to an earlier kernel. Please remember to accept my answer if it was helpful.

Comment: i tried, turns out 4.15 is the only version i currently have, i will install 4.14 now and boot with it

Comment: See if GRUB has the -32 or earlier kernel, or you can try the kernel outlined in the bug report.

Comment: i have tried both 4.15.03-32 and 4.14.35, neither worked. again, i am now getting errors when attempting to install either Jeremy's or Larry's repos. i will continue trying to fix the issue tomorrow

Comment: Not sure whether this bug affects RTL8723**D**E too (which is the one @rakan316 has).